# В слайдере swipper в битрикс не срабатывает буллеты в пагинации при перелистывание слайдов

Tags: html, css, битрикс, swiper

В слайдере swipper в битрикс не срабатывают буллеты в пагинации при перелистывание слайдов. Получается что перелистывание на кнопку- у меня булеты переключаются, а вот когда перелистываю мышкой- не работает. Буду рад любой помощи!
Ссылка на сайт, где размещен слайдер- он самый первый:https://aaa-sitrak.ru/
Код компонента:

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>


<style>
    .swipper__icon{
        margin:auto;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        color:orange;

    }
    .custom-prev{
        opacity:1;
        display:flex;
        position:absolute;
        top: 78px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white
    }
    .custom-next{
        display:flex;
justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        position:absolute;
        top: 78px;
    right: -20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white
    }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
  }
    .swiper-button-disabled{
        opacity:0.3;
    }
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .swiper-slide {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }

  .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    width: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-width, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 20px));
    height: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-height, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 3px));
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-border-radius, 10%);
    background: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color, black);
    opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity, 0.2);
  }

  .swiper-pagination-bullet-active.swiper-pagination-bullet-active.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background: rgb(255, 87, 34);
    opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity, 1);
  }
</style>

<div style="position:relative">
<div data-script="slider" data-slider-options='{"autoplay":false,"breakpoints":{"320":{"slidesPerView":1,"spaceBetween":30},"768":{"slidesPerView":3,"spaceBetween":30},"1200":{"slidesPerView":3,"spaceBetween":30}},"content_element":"images","js":["js/module-swiper-bundle.esm.browser.min.js","js/module-vue.esm.browser.min.js","js/module-slider.js","js/module-vue-awesome-swiper.js"],"loop":false,"navigation":{"nextEl":".swiper-button-next","prevEl":".swiper-button-prev"},"onClickZoom":false,"pagination":{"bulletActiveClass":"active","clickable":true,"el":".swiper-pagination","bulletElement":"span data-element=\"c2aa4a06-56f3-450d-8842-82437cb71e2b/9e0e10c9-b8de-4b3b-88d7-4ff86242fa81\" data-design-nested=\"Пагинация\""},"sliderColumns":{"max":4,"min":1},"slidesPerGroup":1,"space_between":true}' data-design="c2aa4a06-56f3-450d-8842-82437cb71e2b" class="swiper FinansSlider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem) : ?>
      <?
      $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
      $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
      ?>


      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-element="9d7631ef-ec1b-4cb8-92c0-049c143e2042/d2f87e5a-183b-4795-bca5-716c1d36f6f4" data-design-nested="Слайды" style="width: 350px; margin-right: 30px">
        <a target="" data-popup="" data-order="" data-anchor="" data-slide="" class="cli-partner-link">
          <div class="image-select cli-partner-img" data-element="9d7631ef-ec1b-4cb8-92c0-049c143e2042/0e66e820-0f86-45a1-88b9-c1d48cc5025c" data-design="6aa9a8b0-2ce5-11ed-9e22-c3370a386b11/0e66e820-0f86-45a1-88b9-c1d48cc5025c" data-design-nested="Изображение" style="overflow: visible">
            <? $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["IMAGE"]["VALUE"]); ?>
            <img src="<?= $arFile["SRC"] ?>" alt="" class="" style="
                            height: 100%;
                            object-fit: inherit;
                            border-radius: inherit;
                          " src="" /><!----><!---->
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```